# Wordpress :: Need to Call Ajax Action by extra script.php file in root folder of Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, admin-ajax

We have requirement for run costume script (a php file) in root of wordpress

Simply we have `script.php` file in root of wordpress project.

when I run `https://mywordpress.co/script.php` simply I need to Call Ajax Action with Curl
but some how it is not working. and it respond me `0`

with in file I call below `cURL` code to call ajax action but not working

```
$curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "blakey=blaval",
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(

            "action: create_xxxxx",
            "type: product_variation",
            "id:".$post_id,
            "value:".$xxxxxx,

            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",


          ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl); 

        if ($err) {
          echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
          echo 'cURL response:'.$response.'----------------';
        }
```

How can I call action from external file of php in root of wordpress.
thanks in Advance

Comment: Why you don't want use ajax via javascript?

Comment: Ok Letme Try by add "<script>" in php code

Comment: You can check core wordpress file - https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to make AJAX requests in WordPress is by using `wp_ajax_{$action}` (for logged-in users) and `wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}` (for non-logged-in users) hooks.

The implementation is quite simple:

```
function my_ajax() {
    // do something and return
}
add_action('wp_ajax_my_ajax', 'my_ajax'); // For logged-in users
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax', 'my_ajax'); // For non logged-in users
```

First, you create a function to process your AJAX request. Then, you hook into `wp_ajax_{action}` and/or `wp_ajax_nopriv{action}`. Using both depends on your case.

Then, in your JavaScript code you should do like so:

```
fetch(
    'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    { first_name: 'Tarun', last_name: 'Bariya' }
).then(response => {
    return response.json(); // my_ajax() should return a JSON object
}.then(data => {
    // Do something with data
}));
```